# weka not setting the atribute values when reading unlabeled data from mysql

Tags: mysql, weka

I am trying to have weka read unlabeled data in from mysql. I set the Class attribute to have '?' for all the values but I cant set the types of classes to chose from, such as yes and no. I even tried to use the arff to mysql, used the arff that i had tested on and it loaded everything with null for the class values and has not types. Has anyone done this and I have just missed something in the wiki and docs?

EX

data to the arff to mysql method-> @attribute Class {yes,no}
bla,bla,bla,?

data that gets put into mysql -> @atribute Class{}
bla,bla,bla,null

is there something wrong with the method, if not, how do i using the weka library add the yes and no back

Comment: Do you have some sample data that can be provided for analysis?

Comment: added a bit more explanation, does this help?

Comment: Sorry.  Do you have the method that processes your data, and perhaps a subset of the data you are working with?